# Gauss-Bonnet term in tetrad formalism

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, differential-geometry, topology, gauss-bonnet

In eq. 4 of *https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9508128* it is stated that the Gauss-Bonnet term for gravity in 4d can be written as
$$
S=\frac{1}{4}\int d^{4}x\,\epsilon^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}\epsilon_{abcd}R_{\mu\nu}^{\quad ab}R_{\alpha\beta}^{\quad cd}\,,
$$
in the tetrad formalism, with $\epsilon$ Levi-Civita tensor and $R$ Riemann tensor.
In general this term is defined in a different way, as
$$
S\propto\int d^{4}x\sqrt{-g}\left(R^{2}-4R^{\mu\nu}R_{\mu\nu}+R^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}R_{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}\right)\,,
$$
more common in the metric formulation of gravity (see eq. 7 in *https://dx.doi.org/10.1088/1361-6382/ac500a*).

How to prove that the two terms are identical? Is there any identity for the product
$$
\epsilon^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}\epsilon_{abcd}\,,
$$
that helps in proving this equivalence?

Comment: Write the Riemann tensors solely with either frame indices or coordinate indices using inverse vierbeins or vierbeins respectively. Then, use the usual relation between the Levi-Civita \textit{symbol} and the determinant of a matrix. After that use the usual identity for the multiplication of the two LC tensors which gives the generalized delta. Expand to deltas, contract things and you should get the result.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol#Product_2